# Why can't I see Tridion item XML in IE in version 2013?

Tags: 2013

In versions 2011 and earlier, you could (on the CM server) paste the TCM uri of an item into the browser address bar in IE and hey presto - the TCM protocol handler enabled you to see the full XML of the item. In 2013 it doesnt work - why is this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears the protocol handler is not installed on your system, which comes along with the COM+ legacy pack. So you have to install the legacy support for COM+ to be able to use the  protocol handler.

If you join the [PowerTools project](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools) and help making them work on 2013, you could use the [ItemXML](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/ItemXML) instead ;).

Comment: This is indeed correct, Protocol Handlers are COM based, and only available if you install the Legacy pack.

Comment: Thanks Bart - yes indeed ItemXML powertool is much better anyway, as you can view from any machine and browser...

Comment: FYI, I've already made a branch of the PowerTools for 2013 that should work fine.